# Cannot access member "safe_search_detection" for type "ImageAnnotatorClient"

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I have this line:

```
from google.cloud.vision import ImageAnnotatorClient

vision = ImageAnnotatorClient()

vision.safe_search_detection(image).safe_search_annotation.adult
```

After enabling type checking on Pylance I'm getting the error:

> Cannot access member "safe_search_detection" for type "ImageAnnotatorClient". Member "safe_search_detection" is unknown

How can I fix it?

I'm using the latest version of google-cloud-vision

Comment: Can you try switching Python's `Type Checking` to `OFF` in your Pylance or set "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "off" ? If this does not work, can you show your snippet of code wherein you are using the line to properly replicate your use case?

Comment: I want type-checking ON, and Google should fix their libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: the below is no longer relevant, as the original post has been updated.

`safe_search_detection()` is a method of the class `vision.ImageAnnotatorClient`, not a method of the library `vision`. You'll need to create a `vision.ImageAnnotatorClient`
 object before you can call `safe_search_detection()`. For example:

```
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
client.safe_search_detection(image).safe_search_annotation.adult
```

You can find more info and Python example code at Google's docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-safe-search#vision_safe_search_detection-python)

Comment: The vision is my instance of ImageAnnotatorClient, the problem lies somewhere else.